# Secure HTTPS connection to Node.js server from client

Tags: node.js, rest, security, ssl, https

I am developing a backend for a mobile application using Node.js to handle HTTPS requests. I have set up an SSL to connect from the client to the server and was wondering if this was secure enough.

I don't have experience with intercepting endpoints from the mobile devices, but I have seen that it is possible for people to monitor internet traffic out of their cellphones and pick up endpoints to server requests. I have seen hacks on tinder where people can see response JSON and even automate swipes by sending http requests to tinder's endpoints.

My real concern is that people will be able to update/read/modify data on my backend. I can implement OAuth2 into my schema as well but I still see cases in which people could abuse the system.

My main question is whether or not using HTTPS is secure enough to protect my data, or if a session authentication system is needed like OAuth2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTPS, providing it is properly configured, will ensure the message was not read or changed en route and that the client can know the server it is talking to is not a fake.

It will secure the transport. It will not secure the application.

For example supposing you have an app that allows you to send a message saying https://www.example.com/transfermoney?from=Kyle&to=BazzaDP&amount=9999.99 and the server does just that based on those parameters. Then I could send that message myself - I've no need to intercept any app messages.

Normally the server needs **authentication** as well as HTTPS to, for example, verify only Kyle user can send above message and not anyone else. HTTPS normally only gives server authentication not client authentication (unless using two way certificate HTTPS).

So the question is, even if an attacker cannot read or alter any messages between app and server can they still cause harm? That is the measure of whether it is secure enough.

Comment: Cool this is helpful. What if the body of the HTTP request is hidden? For example the URL would say https://www.example.com/transfermoney, but the body would contain values like FROM: Kyle TO:BazzaDP.

Comment: Doesn't matter. It's very easy to construct a message like this. Childs play for anyone with even a little experience of computers. Plugins exist for Chrome for example (e.g. Advanced REST Client). It's a key rule of security to not trust user input and to verify it (e.g. check the person logged on has authority to send from Kyle based on a session id is not easy to fake).

Comment: Ok thank you for this explanation. Answered a lot of lingering questions I have had about how the security of a node.js app works.

Answer (score 0):

A SSL connection is only secure with the content you are sending.

SSL encrypts and ensures the authenticity of the whole connection, including the requested method and URL

So i would say just using the SSL encryption is save to transfer data between - i might consider OAuth2 for password etc.

But i would recommend to use GET for retrieval data and post for authorized data

Comment: N ote that the entire URL is probably logged by the server so nothing sensitive should be in the querry string.

Comment: So lets say I do a POST request to update a User Bio String. I should pass all this information through the HTTPS tunnel in the body of the post request. The body will include the user_id and the bio. Is there no way then a man in the middle could see that HTTPS request, change the Bio string, and send the https request to me? Is this essentially what the HTTPS protects against?

Comment: Not if it is encrypted by SSL

Answer (score 0):

You're building an armored tunnel between two open fields.

Assuming that you use current SSL protocols and settings, and valid certificates from trusted issuers, you can pretty much assume the network is OK.

However it's still entirely possible to compromise any or all of your transaction from the client. Security really depends on the device and how well it's configured and patched.